# Examples of prophecies that didn't and cannot come to pass?

Tags: history, tanach, nevua-prophecy, navi-prophets

Are there any examples of prophecies recorded by established Jewish prophets in Tanach which were about a specific time and/or a specific people and did not come to pass, and subsequently cannot come to pass?

As a completely made up example if there was a prophecy that Ammonites would all be swallowed up by the sea, such a prophecy did not happen historically and cannot happen any longer as there are no longer a people known as the Ammonites.

**Note**: I am **NOT** asking if there are statements from Chazal that reinterpret the prophecy either symbolically or to be referring to something other than the plain meaning of the pesukim.

Comment: I don't know offhand but we wouldn't consider it to be theologically problematic if the unfulfilled prophecies were negatives/punishments (such as in your example of a people swallowed by the sea or more classically נינווה). Negative prophecies do not have to occur as there is always the possibility of teshubha. See H. Yesode ha-Torah 10:8-10.

Comment: This is a classic example: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81889/20472.

Comment: Isn't Jonah's prophecy to Ninveh literally this? @Deuteronomy

Comment: This topic is covered in the Mossad Harav Kook commentary to Daniel. If someone has access, perhaps they might summarize the points made there.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, as I note in my comment above "or more classically נינווה"